# How to open camera with GLSurfaceView.Renderer

Tags: android, glsurfaceview

I'm trying to build a camera view as background.
I want to load my camera inside `GLSurfaceView.Renderer` class.

My class:

```
public class ModelRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
...
```

My question is, is it possible to load camera preview as background in `GLSurfaceView.Renderer`?

I'm using Android studio.

Comment: If you're asking this.... get your feet wet and try.. dare to make mistakes. I know you can do it!!

Answer (score 0):

Well It isn't really adding the preview as a "background" but you certainly can draw the camera preview to the GLSurfaceView and attach a renderer to the surface to do the drawing. There are numerous examples of doing so. I would search around for them but I believe Grafika has what you are looking for.